# Magento 2 - how to get customer entity_id when order is placed rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How to get `entity_id` after order is placed.

How can i get order details with entity id in Magento2 rest api ?

Comment: you wany customer entity id from order?

Comment: yes, by using entity id can we get order details ?

Comment: mean entity id  means `Customer Id`? or order id?

Comment: order id 
and how can i get order details of specific user.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook to sales_model_service_quote_submit_success event, It is execute after order is placed.

Add event to your_module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="your_module_sales_model_service_quote_submit_success" instance="Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitSuccessObserver"/>
</event>
```

Create observer

```
namespace Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitSuccessObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Fires when sales_order_place_after is dispatched
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //Order information
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        //Quote information
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        //Get customer_id from order
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();

        //Or Get customer_id from quote
        $customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get order_id or entity_id after placing order

Comment: Use `$order->getId()`

Answer (score 0):

Header:Authorization Bearer Key

use admin token

baseurl/rest/all/V1/orders/orderid

baseurl/rest/all/V1/orderlist?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=15

Comment: how can i get order_id or entity_id after placing order

Comment: Use sales_order_place_after event where you can get all order details

Comment: i am using rest api so how can i get it

Comment: You are using rest API to place order ? If yes it will return order id