# Magento 2: \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository is not working in observer

Tags: magento2

```
$orderId = $order->getId();
                     $objectManager = $this->dataHelper->getObjectManager();
                     $order12 = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
```

This code is not working in the observer. I am sending data through rest API.
Getting issue in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Can you please provide the solution?

Thanks

Comment: What event do You use? Maybe this help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242459/magento-2-how-to-get-customer-entity-id-when-order-is-placed-rest-api

Comment: Which event you want to observe?

Comment: sales_order_save_after

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
$order12 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface')->get($orderId);
```

**OR**

```
$order12 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
```

Comment: I have also tried with this Magento\Sales\Model\Order. Not getting result

Comment: Then try 1st solution with Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface